# Elasticsearch: on full cluster restart - Shards are not recovering and remaining as unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm using elasticsearch 2.1.1 and have a cluster of 8 nodes(3 master-nodes + 5 data-nodes). I've tried full cluster restart but ended up with weird issue(I couldn't find any issue in logs).

I've just shutdown all nodes and restarted them. Everything was went well till here but after the restart the shards were not recovering and they just stuck at unassigned state.

My cluster has sufficient disk space and I restarted all the datanodes. Still all the shards were simply not recovering. *Could someone help me on this?*

I've tried tweaking configurations like `gateway.recover_after_nodes` and `"cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "all"` but couldn't succeeded.

**Update:**

The problem here is initially I had replica 4 i.e I had 5 copies of data included with primary in 5 datanodes. When I restarted the cluster, I just started only 3 data nodes which contains max of 3 copies of data but to prevent allocating stale shard copy ES uses config called `index.recovery.initial_shards` for which default value is quorum(4 in my case). So in order to make shards recovering from full cluster restart either I need to make at least quorum data nodes up or need to decrease replica accordingly( <=3 in my case).

**Edit:**

Sample Results(have many indices like these) of `GET /_cat/indices?v`:

```
health status index                         pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
red    open   kafka8-2016.07                10   3                                                   
red    open   kafka8-2016.06                10   3                                                   
red    open   .kibana                        1   3
```

Sample Results(have many shards like these) of `GET /_cat/shards?v`

```
index             shard prirep    state      docs store ip node 
kafka8-2016.07     5     p      UNASSIGNED                    
kafka8-2016.07     5     r      UNASSIGNED                    
kafka8-2016.07     5     r      UNASSIGNED                    
kafka8-2016.07     5     r      UNASSIGNED                    
kafka8-2016.07     1     p      UNASSIGNED                    
kafka8-2016.07     1     r      UNASSIGNED                    
kafka8-2016.07     1     r      UNASSIGNED                    
kafka8-2016.07     1     r      UNASSIGNED
```

Results of `GET _cat/nodes?v`:

```
host   ip heap.percent ram.percent load node.role master name     
host1 ip1            0          82 0.00 d         -      data-3   
host2 ip2            0          87 0.00 d         -      data-4   
host3 ip3            1          80 0.00 -         *      master-2 
host4 ip4            1          73 0.00 -         m      master-1 
host4 ip5            1          84 0.00 d         -      data-1
```

Comment: Please update your question with the result you get from running `curl localhost:9200/_cat/shards?v` and `curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`

Comment: And all your nodes are up and running properly? Can you add this: `curl localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v`

Comment: Three nodes(2 data nodes + 1 master-node) are down, but I have sufficient replication and zen.minimum required master-nodes

Comment: Run this command and provide the output: `POST /_cluster/reroute
{
  "dry_run": true, 
  "commands": [
    {
      "allocate": {
        "index": "kafka8-2016.07",
        "shard": 1,
        "node": "data-1",
        "allow_primary": true
      }
    }
  ]
}`. From the command above two very important things: `"allow_primary": true` will try to allocate the primary. And this can lead to data loss. **But**, the second important thing, `"dry_run": true` is specified which means the `_reroute` command is just a simulation.

Comment: Any interesting things in the output? :-)

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I've resolved it. Thanks a lot Val and @AndreiStefan for your support. I still need to find root cause for this weird behaviour. I'm suspecting it as a bug, however I'll post all the info after I figured out root cause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing full cluster restart you need to start at least quorum of your data nodes. This is configured through `index.recovery.initial_shards` which prevents allocation stale shard copy.

> `index.recovery.initial_shards`
>
> A primary shard is only recovered only
>   if there are enough nodes available to allocate sufficient replicas to
>   form a quorum. It can be set to:
>
> quorum (default)
>
> quorum-1 (or half)
>
> full
>
> full-1.
>
> Number values are
>   also supported, e.g. 1.

You can read more about this configuration in official docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/index-modules.html#dynamic-index-settings)

You can find similar issue explained in this [elasticsearch github comment](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/18393#issuecomment-219671552)